# How to use C, C++ program or classes in objective C (Xcode)?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c

Currently I am trying to use C++ class in objective C. I followed the steps of this website tutorial 
https://www.sitepoint.com/using-c-and-c-in-an-ios-app-with-objective-c/

So I am able to access and print "Hello C++" string on text box on button click. but how to access main function as already `main()` is present in objective C.

I have included external "libzip" library which is zip-unzip operating library which is written in C and I want to access it in objective C so that, whenever i click on any button it should unzip specific directory in ios device and return data from that zip file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I am totally new in XCODE and objective C.

Comment: @RawN  ok Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the folder "Supporting Files" for the file called `main.m`.

Rename it to `main.mm`

Now main is a c++ main.

[image]

Comment: so it means all coding C++ i need to do here right ? and how to access it in Main story boards button? so that when i click on button particular function will get called.  ?

Comment: @AbhinandanDharmadikari, you can add/rename other files to ".mm" and add C++ code there. In order to connect your storyboard to C++ functions, you have to make an Objective-C class inside an .m file, and call C++ functions from Objective-C methods inside that class.

Comment: @FreeNickname you mean a .mm file

Comment: @RichardHodges, yes, sorry, a typo. Thanks! (can't edit that comment anymore).